# How to uniquely identify a given clojure function?

Tags: clojure, identity

I am currently working on a simple event dispatcher for a minesweeper game I've written in clojure.

As a starting point I thought about having something like:

```
(def receivers (atom {}))
```

With a register function that appends a given function to a particular map of events with a nested set per event, e.g. {:do-sth #{func1 func2}}

As I learned, as soon as you add a function again to the namespace, it had a different identity, which of course makes sense but lets my approach fail.

Is there a way to uniquely identify a function that might be passed in as parameter? Otherwise I'd have to provide a unique id for every function which I'd like to avoid if possible.

**UPDATE**

Going with the suggestion from clyfe, I ended up with the following first approach:

```
(def receivers (atom {}))

(defn register 
  [event wrapped-function]
  (if 
    (var? wrapped-function)    
    (swap! receivers 
           #(assoc %1 %2 (conj (or (get %1 %2) #{}) %3))
           event 
           wrapped-function)
    (throw (IllegalStateException. 
            "wrapperd function must be a var"))))


(defn bar
  []
  "bar")


(register :foo #'bar)
```

Comment: "as soon as you add a function again to the namespace" is that due to code reloading, that is making you problems ?

Comment: yeah, probably no "real-life issue" but I am currently using lighttable and as soon as I run my stuff it adds the functions again while the atom stays as it is.

Comment: I thought about adding some metadata to the function and throwing an exception in case it does not exist. But looks like a dirty workaround to me

Comment: Try using defonce instead of def for your atom. This will prevent your receivers from being redefined each time you reload your namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is due to code reloading, you can store the function's enclosing var in the set  `{:ev #{#'f1 #'f2}}`, that stays the same after reloading:

```
user=> (defn foo [] 1)
#'user/foo
user=> foo
#<user$foo user$foo@540e6cef>
user=> (def f1 foo)
#'user/f1
user=> (def f2 #'foo)
#'user/f2
user=> (defn foo [] 2)
#'user/foo
user=> foo
#<user$foo user$foo@35d4a23f>
user=> (f1)
1
user=> (f2)
2
```

Comment: Nice! The only constraint I see is that I have to do this before I pass the function as an argument to another function, right? I tried to apply it inside a different function but got an error that he var cannot be resolved.  Besides that, is there any drawback with this solution I might not be aware of?

Comment: You'll have to provide a test for your specific situation so I can understand what you mean.